# Clear cache before running some Selenium WebDriver tests using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browser-cache

I am working on Selenium WebDriver automation in java programming language. In my test suite that initiates the browser window once and perform all the tests. I want to clear the browser cache before running some tests without restarting the browser. Is there any command/function, that can achieve the purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

This is what I use in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//settings-ui').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

You can try converting these into Java. Hope this will help! :)

Answer (score 7):

At least in Chrome, I strongly believe that if you go incognito you wont to have to clean up your cookies. You can set your options like following (the :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def _options():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    #options.add_argument("--test-type")
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') if os.name == 'nt' else None # Windows workaround
    options.add_argument("--verbose")
    return options
```

and call like this:

```
with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.implicitly_wait(conf["implicitly_wait"])
    driver.get(conf["url"])
```

Comment: Not convinced its usefull for an end-to-end test, because at this point, you are no longer using the same environment as a customer would.

Answer (score 5):

For IE

```
DesiredCapabilities ieCap =  DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
```

For Chrome:

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=583

To delete cookies:

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Comment: `DesiredCapabilities` has been deprecated

Answer (score 5):

The following code is based on @An Khang 's answers. and it is working properly on Chrome 78.

```
ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();

    chromeDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    chromeDriver.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData");
    chromeDriver.findElementByXPath("//settings-ui").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    return chromeDriver;
```

Comment: This selector no longer returns any elements in 81.0.4

Comment: This solution worked for me, I am using chrome 86 , Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work in Chrome 87, the enter key doesn't trigger clearing the cache.

Answer (score 3):

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//settings-ui")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

On Google chrome you can use this script:

```html
        driver.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData");       
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        WebElement clearData =  (WebElement) jse.executeScript("return document.querySelector(\"body > settings-ui\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"#main\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"settings-basic-page\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"#basicPage > settings-section:nth-child(8) > settings-privacy-page\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"#clearBrowsingDataConfirm\")");
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", clearData);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def get_webdriver(width: int = 1600, height: int = 1200):
try:
    global browser
    if browser is not None:
        return browser
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--width=' + str(width))
    options.add_argument('--height=' + str(height))
    options.add_argument("--disable-cache")

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.cache.disk.enable", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.cache.memory.enable", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.cache.offline.enable", False)
    profile.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False)
    options.profile = profile

    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    window_size = browser.execute_script("""
    return [window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth + arguments[0],
      window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight + arguments[1]];
    """, width, height)
    browser.set_window_size(*window_size)
    return browser
except Exception as err:
    logging.error(f"Can't install GeckoDriverManager. Error: {err}")
```

and use browser

```
    browser = get_webdriver(width=width, height=height)
    browser.delete_all_cookies()
    browser.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)  # Maximum wait time in seconds
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    png_image = browser.get_screenshot_as_png()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
```

you need to import the Keys in newer version and change the last line to findElement by xpath

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//settings-ui")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what Ambesh Srivastava answered?

Comment: I only wrote it, because in newer versions the import is needed.

Comment: Not working for Chrome v96. Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

what i found working for myself was adding chromium flag:

--disk-cache-size=0

not sure if it clears cache, but any cache related problems disappeared in my case

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34494188)