# Clear caches in Chrome browser using selenium Chrome driver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am coding with Python 3 and Selenium. I want automatically clear the cache in chrome, the timeframe does not matter.

This is my current solution:

```
driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//settings-ui').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(10)
```

This solution however does not click the "Delete Data" Button and I dont know why...

Chromedriver version is 85.0.4183.87 and Selenium 3.141.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] also what are the versions of chrome and the driver?

Comment: based on your chrome version I belive [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970855/clear-cache-before-running-some-selenium-webdriver-tests-using-java#comment109037276_59102655) explains why this doesn't work.

Comment: Chromedriver version is 85.0.4183.87 and Selenium 3.141. The problem is this line: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//settings-ui').send_keys(Keys.ENTER) I do not get an error message but the script just does not click the button.

Comment: Quoting the aforementioned comment : *"This selector no longer returns any elements in 81.0.4"*

Comment: Yes, Ive read it. Still yesterday these code lines still were working. :(

Comment: Please edit the versions of both Chromedriver and Selenium into your question itself.

Comment: Did it, do you maybe know an answer?

Comment: I personally don't know but this is a well-written question (especially after adding all relevant details) so now we wait for someone who is following the [tag:selenium] tag to come and answer it. Might take a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Actions + Keyboard keys to reach this button (Tab and Enter). You need to press Tab 7 times and then, Enter. So, use: TabX(7); Enter();. Works fine for me (C#).

```
    public void TabX(int valor)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < valor; i++)
        {
            Actions act = new Actions(driver);
            act.SendKeys(Keys.Tab).Build().Perform();
        }
    }

    public void Enter()
    {
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Build().Perform();
    }
```