# Get back stored data without generated values

Tags: java, cucumber, selenide

I have a test case, which wants to create a user with some specific and a generated data, and it wants to store the generated data to repeat this method again. However, when it runs the second creation, I get the stored data + freshly generated data. I want to get back the stored data without generated values.

```
@When("I create a new user with id: {smartString}, " +
      "name: {smartString} and birth: {smartString}")
public void CreateNewUnit(String id, String name, String date) {

    String testName = name + "-" + RandomUtils.getRandomNumeric(6);
    szepScenarioContext.storeVariable(testName, "testName");

    $(getBy("Create button")).click();
    $(getBy("Id field")).sendKeys(id);
    $(getBy("Name field")).sendKeys(testName);
    $(getBy("Birth field")).sendKeys(date);
    $(getBy("Submit button")).click();
}

Scenario: Create a user
    Given I navigate to the XY page
    When I create a new user with id: "123", name: "Test" and birth: "1999.12.12."
    And I create a new user with id: "123", name: "<$testName>" and birth: "1999.12.12."
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear cache before running some Selenium WebDriver tests using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970855/clear-cache-before-running-some-selenium-webdriver-tests-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

Each time you are calling the same step, you are using the `name` parameter that you get via the step parameters, you add a random number and you store the value in a variable called `testName`. So each time you use the step, you are overwriting the value of this variable.

If you want to reuse that value the second time you are calling the same step, you need to add a logic to check if you already have a stored value and use it, or generate a new one if the `szepScenarioContext` has no variable stored already.
Something like this:

```
public void CreateNewUnit(String id, String name, String date) {
   
   Optional<String> testName = szepScenarioContext.getStoredVariable("testName");
   if (testName.isEmpty())
   {
      String newTestName = name + "-" + RandomUtils.getRandomNumeric(6);
      szepScenarioContext.storeVariable(testName, "testName");
   } 

   $(getBy("Create button")).click();
   $(getBy("Id field")).sendKeys(id);
   $(getBy("Name field")).sendKeys(testName);
   $(getBy("Birth field")).sendKeys(date);
   $(getBy("Submit button")).click();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Unfortunately I cannot run the if statement, the code doesn't identify the empty string so I get this:  'Optional[]'

Comment: The code I added assumes the new method "getStoredVariable" from szepScenarioContext is implemented to return an Optional<String> object. Did you implement it as such? You need to add the following import: `import java.util.Optional;`. There are other alternatives besides working with Optional, but the main idea is the same as I stated: you need to check if you already have a value generated and retrieve it, or you need to generate it an store it for subsequent calls.