How to make api requests with Selenium in c#?
I am making api requests in Selenium by navigating to the url, but the response is cached and not updated as frequent as the actual data is.
I need to login to the page with an external 2 factor authentication before I can request the data, which is why I chose to do it with Selenium.
Is there a way to make api requests that aren't cached?
Pseudo c# code:
var options = new FirefoxOptions();
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
string url = "https://www. ...";

Login(driver, url + "/login"); //navigate to 2 factor authorization login

string getId = "1001";
string apiPath = url + "/api/get/" + getId;
while (true)
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(apiPath);
    DecodeData(driver.PageSource); //extract data from response
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}


This seems like a pretty shaky way to do API testing - what about non-GET API endpoints?

You could probably get by using some of the methods in this question to clear the browser cache: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970855/clear-cache-before-running-some-selenium-webdriver-tests-using-java - or you could just add some extra query string parameter with a random value to prevent the browser from caching

Just use something that does API calls and does not try to simulate a browser. Curl?  Postman?

if you just execute javascript of document.reload() (Or I think driver has refresh method as well) you will get the latest version of that page, regardless of browser-side caching. (Right now I guess the browser has no reason to navigate anywhere OR load from cache because the URL has not changed, and the page is still in memory) I had thought that Selenium actually would re-run the request, though. (I'm assuming you've already verified that it does not...)  It should send navigate straight through without relying on change of location.href.

Pretty shaky indeed, and it doesn’t feel like the right way of doing it, but it’s the best I have come up with. Thanks for the tips on forcing refreshed/uncached data! Will try it out. I am actually doing a bunch of calls to different getId’s in each loop. So time could also be an issue.

each get should run through normal browser caching checks... so if cached response is determined to be "stale" it'll load new content. If not, it'll get from cached response. (unless they set certain headers such as "no-store" where it would always be fresh even when using back button which has no staleness check) So if you don't see a change it should mean there is actually no change on the backend.
